# calling javascript namespace function from within jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, module

I want to populate a jquery ui modal dialog with values from an array in this module:

```
var WsdArrays = function() {
     var arr = [["the boy is going home", "wsd_aud1"],
      ["You and I are friends", "wsd_aud2"],
      ["He has a book of mine", "wsd_aud3"],
      ["He will run to his home", "wsd_aud4"],
      ...          ];         
    return {
        values: function(index1, index2) {
        return arr[index1][index2];
        }
    };
}();
```

this works OK when called like this:

```
console.log(WsdArrays.values(0, 0));
```

but it does not work when the module function is called within a jquery statement with arguments generated by the jquery click event thus:

```
jQuery("span.ws_dialog_icon").on("click",function(evnt) {
  jQuery("div#ws_dialog").dialog("open");
  evnt.stopPropagation();
  var elementId = evnt.target.id,
      index1 = elementId.substr(7), //strips chars from ids like "wsd_img01"
      index2 = 0,
      arrayVals = WsdArrays.values(index1, index2);
  jQuery("div#wsd_text").text(arrayVals);
});
```

What needs to be changed here?

Comment: `but it does not work when the module function is called within a jquery statement ` does it cause an exception or just returns the wrong result? What does the console say? What are the values you pass in? Have you tried adding a `console(index1, index2)` inside your `values` function? Also, where is `WsdArrays` defined? You say `namespaced function` where is the namespace? Is it in the same closure as the jQuery code, in the same file or completely separate?

Answer (score 0):

Use `window` to make it more global.

So set it like so:

```
window.WsdArrays = function() {
     var arr = [["the boy is going home", "wsd_aud1"],
      ["You and I are friends", "wsd_aud2"],
      ["He has a book of mine", "wsd_aud3"],
      ["He will run to his home", "wsd_aud4"],
      ...          ];         
    return {
        values: function(index1, index2) {
        return arr[index1][index2];
        }
    };
}();
```

This way it will sit in the global namespace, if it is made within another function this will also work. If you declare it with `var` inside another function it will only be available within that function.

Comment: Dialog box displayed but not populated. JSHint says WsdArrays is undefined?? I was getting this message originally :( @Jordan Ramstad

Answer (score 0):

I think `scoping` is here indeed the main issue.
But instead of littering the `window`/global namespace I suggest using another namespace:

```
var app=function($){
    var WsdArrays = function() {
        var arr = [["the boy is going home", "wsd_aud1"],
        ["You and I are friends", "wsd_aud2"],
        ["He has a book of mine", "wsd_aud3"],
        ["He will run to his home", "wsd_aud4"],
        ...          ];         
        return {
                 values: function(index1, index2) {
                         return arr[index1][index2];
               }
        };
    }();
    $("span.ws_dialog_icon").on("click",function(evnt) { 
       $("div#ws_dialog").dialog("open");
       evnt.stopPropagation();
       var elementId = evnt.target.id,
       index1 = elementId.substr(7), //strips chars from ids like "wsd_img01"
       index2 = 0,
       arrayVals = WsdArrays.values(index1, index2);
       $("div#wsd_text").text(arrayVals);
   });
}(jQuery);
```

So, there is no need for using global scope, and WsdArrays is visible to the `onClick`.

Besides: why aren't you using a dictionary-approach?

```
var WsdArrays=function(){
    var whatEverString={
         "wsd_aud1","the boy is going home",
         "wsd:auds","you and i are friends"
    };
    return {
        values:function(id){ return whatEverString[id]; }
    }
}
```

Another thing: 
Why are you encapsulating a simple function in an IFFE? Only for namespacing reasons?
A simple function would be sufficient.

Comment: the code doesn't work (after removing the ... ) no dialog box is displayed whereas  before the dialog box was displayed but was empty. I'm using an array because I thought it would retrieve values the quicker than a literal object. @Thomas Junk

Comment: could you make up a http://jsfiddle.net/, where we see some more of your code and what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Try parseInt:

```
index1 = parseInt(elementId.substr(7)),
```

The reason is your `index1` without `parseInt` is a string `"01"` after calling `elementId.substr(7)` for `"wsd_img01"`. This will cause problem as `arr["01"]` returns `undefined` which causes exception when you call `arr["01"][index2]`. As you can see in the following [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dmNjG/)

When we use `parseInt`, `index1` becomes 1 which does not cause problem.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dmNjG/1/)